# Get errors featureclasses of Trace Network ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, trace

I try to analyse road featureclass for errors of topology and I use Trace network tool in arcpy.
I cannot just create topology and add some rules, because it doesn't work like I want.
When I use the desktop version, the layer "%name_network Trace network" is added with 4 sublayers (featureclasses) and we can see the errors un this sublayers :PointErrors, LineErrors, SystemJunctions and DirtyAreas.
But If I create the same network in arcpy, I cannot access these 4 featureclasses via ListFeatureClasses(), it just doesn't them see, return gives only mylines featureclass.
Also, I cannot just use the name of featureclass, because it has 3 random digits. Verify 999 differents paths isn't smart.

```
import arcpy
import os
def read_errors(gdb, fdName, fcName, networkName, output):
    arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(gdb, 'temp_fd'))
    fdatasetPath = os.path.join(gdb, fdName)
    fclassPath = os.path.join(fdatasetPath, fcName)
    src = arcpy.Describe(fdatasetPath).spatialReference
    # create temp featuredataset and copy featureclass
    tempFDName = 'temp_fd'
    tempFDPath = os.path.join(gdb, tempFDName)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb, tempFDName, src)
    tempFCName = 'temp_fc'
    tempFCPath = os.path.join(tempFDPath, tempFCName)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fclassPath, tempFCPath)
    try:
        fcNameParam = f"{tempFCName} SIMPLE_EDGE"
        # we create traceNetwork, it creates 4 featureclasses for errors
        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        traceNetwork = arcpy.CreateTraceNetwork_tn(
            in_feature_dataset=tempFDPath,
            in_trace_network_name=networkName,
            input_edges=fcNameParam
        )
        # enable topology add errors into 4 featureclasses
        arcpy.EnableNetworkTopology_tn(traceNetwork)
        datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
        # print(datasets) # 2 datasets ['fds', 'temp_fd']
        for ds in datasets:
            print(f"featureClasses in : {ds}")
            featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds)
            print(featureClasses) 
        # in temp_fd I have only temp_fc, but it must to be more
        # I chage workspace for search into tempFD, it won't work otherwise
        arcpy.env.workspace = tempFDPath
        print(arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type="TraceNetwork")) # I see 'myNetwork', OK
        myNetwork = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type="TraceNetwork")[0]
        # print(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=myNetwork))
        # ERROR 160069: The dataset was not found. but it's there
        print(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()) 
        # only ['temp_fc'] displayed. but there is 3 other FeatureClasses
        for i in range(200, 500):
            try:
                fcErrorName = f"TN_{i}_LineErrors"
                fcErrorPath = os.path.join(tempFDPath, fcErrorName)
                nbr = arcpy.GetCount_management(fcErrorPath)
                print(f"{fcErrorName} contains {nbr} elements")
                # TN_407_LineErrors contains 2 elements
                break
            except Exception:
                pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        # arcpy.Delete_management(tempFDPath)
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_errors(
        gdb = r"C:\Users\Aleksandr.Matveev.z\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject11\04oct.gdb",
        fdName = "fds",
        fcName = 'mylines',
        networkName = "myNetwork",
        output = "out"
    )
```

[image: screenshot]

My question is : how can I get these featureclasses in arcpy in the other way then using loop?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code.  Are you running the code withing ArcGIS Pro's Python window, or in a separate IDE?

Comment: Which workspace (eg, GDB, folder, etc) are those layers in?  Use the "Source" panel of the "Properties" window to find out.  Is this the same workspace that your are running `ListFeatureClasses()` on?

Comment: @SonofaBeach I use differents workspaces: GDB and datasets. The featureclasses are there, but I can't see it using ListFeatureClasses()

Comment: @SonofaBeach I run this code in a separate IDE

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've done this, but I _think_ you can get the reference to it directly by name. Use the name of your trace network + the error name. From your Pro screen shot, that would be: `myNetwork Trace Network\\Point Errors`. Inside Python that "virtual reference should exist", because, if I remember correctly, the `myNetwork Trace Network` is actually a _group layer_ (well technically a network trace, but behaves like a group layer), with layers inside.

Comment: Some code samples here for working with group layers https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/listing-layers-in-a-group/td-p/736543

Comment: @KHibma I succeeded to get this layers like you told me. But it works only if you run your script from a toolbox. In other way loop is inevitable. thank you for help

Comment: the solution :
numberOfProblemLayer = str(arcpy.Describe(traceNetworkPath).associationSource.name).split("_")[1]
        errorLayers = []
        for errorLayer in ["PointErrors", "LineErrors"]:
            errorLayerPath = os.path.join(fdPath, f"TN_{numberOfProblemLayer}_{errorLayer}")
            if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(errorLayerPath).getOutput(0)) != 0:
                arcpy.AddMessage("Some overlapping SLNet features were found.")
                errorLayers.append(errorLayerPath)